# Cannot find module '/workspace/use' on Cloudbuild

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I am attempting to make a deployment to firebase using cloud build triggers, everything seems to work fine until it reaches the `use` command in my `cloudbuild.yml` and cannot find the `workspace/use` module. Has anyone seen anything like this before?

```
   steps:
    - name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/latest'
      args: ['use', '$_PROJECT_NAME']
      secretEnv: ['FIREBASE_TOKEN']
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
      dir: 'functions'
      args: ['install']
    - name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase'
      args: ['deploy']
      secretEnv: ['FIREBASE_TOKEN']
    images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/latest']
    secrets:
    - kmsKeyName: 'projects/<project_name>/locations/global/keyRings/ci-ring/cryptoKeys/deployment'
      secretEnv:
        FIREBASE_TOKEN: <token>
```

Error logs:

```
  starting build "e58cd1fb-83ac-473e-8619-be5993c85ff3"
    
    FETCHSOURCE
    Fetching storage object: gs://<project_name>_cloudbuild/source/1611438707.861363-3e7c162fc67f4c0b9265048dc271a97c.tgz#1611438709526281
    Copying gs://<project_name>_cloudbuild/source/1611438707.861363-3e7c162fc67f4c0b9265048dc271a97c.tgz#1611438709526281...
    / [0 files][    0.0 B/  3.8 MiB]                                                
    / [1 files][  3.8 MiB/  3.8 MiB]                                                
    Operation completed over 1 objects/3.8 MiB.                                      
    BUILD
    Starting Step #0
    Step #0: Pulling image: gcr.io/<project_name>/latest
    Step #0: Using default tag: latest
    Step #0: latest: Pulling from <project_name>/latest
    Step #0: cbdbe7a5bc2a: Already exists
    Step #0: f98f8aade4b1: Pulling fs layer
    Step #0: 6c9c37ffd044: Pulling fs layer
    Step #0: 003e8eba0035: Pulling fs layer
    Step #0: 66809d8b3441: Pulling fs layer
    Step #0: b433e12bb2bb: Pulling fs layer
    Step #0: e41dc8d53a22: Pulling fs layer
    Step #0: a5334e5fd71b: Pulling fs layer
    Step #0: 0555f0644d57: Pulling fs layer
    Step #0: 66809d8b3441: Waiting
    Step #0: b433e12bb2bb: Waiting
    Step #0: e41dc8d53a22: Waiting
    Step #0: a5334e5fd71b: Waiting
    Step #0: 7531da0f40aa: Pulling fs layer
    Step #0: 0555f0644d57: Waiting
    Step #0: 7531da0f40aa: Waiting
    Step #0: 003e8eba0035: Download complete
    Step #0: 6c9c37ffd044: Verifying Checksum
    Step #0: 6c9c37ffd044: Download complete
    Step #0: 66809d8b3441: Download complete
    Step #0: e41dc8d53a22: Verifying Checksum
    Step #0: e41dc8d53a22: Download complete
    Step #0: a5334e5fd71b: Verifying Checksum
    Step #0: a5334e5fd71b: Download complete
    Step #0: b433e12bb2bb: Verifying Checksum
    Step #0: b433e12bb2bb: Download complete
    Step #0: f98f8aade4b1: Verifying Checksum
    Step #0: f98f8aade4b1: Download complete
    Step #0: 7531da0f40aa: Verifying Checksum
    Step #0: 7531da0f40aa: Download complete
    Step #0: 0555f0644d57: Download complete
    Step #0: f98f8aade4b1: Pull complete
    Step #0: 6c9c37ffd044: Pull complete
    Step #0: 003e8eba0035: Pull complete
    Step #0: 66809d8b3441: Pull complete
    Step #0: b433e12bb2bb: Pull complete
    Step #0: e41dc8d53a22: Pull complete
    Step #0: a5334e5fd71b: Pull complete
    Step #0: 0555f0644d57: Pull complete
    Step #0: 7531da0f40aa: Pull complete
    Step #0: Digest: sha256:xxxx
    Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/qualle-web/latest:latest
    Step #0: gcr.io/qualle-web/latest:latest
    Step #0: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
    Step #0:   throw err;
    Step #0:   ^
    Step #0: 
    Step #0: Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/use'
    Step #0:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    Step #0:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    Step #0:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    Step #0:     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
    Step #0:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    Step #0:   requireStack: []
    Step #0: }
    Finished Step #0
    ERROR
    ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/<project_name>/latest" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Comment: What do you intend to happen when Cloud Build runs `gcr.io/qualle-web/latest:latest use ...`? Does this command succeed if you run it from your host? The error is unclear but the build is failing at this first step and so something is amiss with what you're trying to do. `/workspace` is Cloud Build's default working directory. It's unclear why it's appending `use` to this path

Comment: I wonder whether that container has no entrypoint and so Cloud Build is taking `use` as the entrypoint. That would make sense. There's definitely something incorrect with that container. Can you add its Dockerfile?